# Google maps not working correctly in Ionic v1

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am having issue regarding with my map in Ionic v1 app. Just a while ago my map doesn't work correctly. Please refer to the picture below:

[image]

Some of my map functions didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.

this is occurs because of googles new policy. follow the provided link and by selecting your project add payment option, billing information and card information, which will fix the problem and you will not initially.

Comment: so i will pay for it?

Comment: no you dont need to pay just add payment method it will not charge anything

Comment: Really? How sure you are?

Comment: ref. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing

Comment: and there is an offer  $300 credit for free
Sign up and get $300 to spend on Google Cloud Platform over the next 12 months.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179954/discussion-between-parvej-mallick-and-trish-siquian).